# How to Turn a View into Landscape Mode in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, view, interface-builder, landscape

In xcode 3 there is that little arrow next to the view title. That little button has gone in xcode 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click the icon on the right hand menu: attribute inspector, this should show Orientation under Simulated Metrics. The Utilites should be opened for that. Look at the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Nope, I really liked the the turning arrow. XCode4 is strange in many ways.